# array_agg_transfn called in non-aggregate context postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.4, greenplum

I have a week_value column from the table "vin_temp_table" with the following values.I am using Greenplum database with postgres 8.2 on it.

```
633
423
389
348
341
326
321
316
301
293
291
1
2
```

Now I am trying to aggregate the next 13 values from the current column and am trying to put them in an array using the following query but I get the error "array_agg_transfn called in non-aggregate context postgres". Could some one help me out. Thanks!

```
select a."Week_value", array_agg(a."Week_value") over(order by prod_name,week_date desc rows between 0 preceding and 12 following) 
from vin_temp_table a
```

So,for example the first row array result contains 13 values including itself until the next 13 column values {633,423, 389, 348, 341, 326, 321, 316, 301, 293, 291 ,1 ,2 }

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get column values from multiple rows as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993021/get-column-values-from-multiple-rows-as-array)

Comment: I answered at your [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993021/get-column-values-from-multiple-rows-as-array/21995417#21995417): `rows between frame_start AND frame_end` syntax is just not available in your old version.