# Get column values from multiple rows as array

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-8.4, window-functions

I am trying to fetch column values as an array in order to use them in the [function `array_agg_transfn()` to calculate the median value as defined in the Postgres Wiki.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median)

The column values of a particular column I fetch based on the current row. For example, 13 rows below the current row. I tried using the following query:

```
select a."Week_value", 
       array_agg(a."Week_value") 
            over(order by prod_name,week_date desc 
                 rows between 0 preceding and 12 following) 
from vin_temp_table
```

But got this error message:

> ```
> array_agg_transfn called in non-aggregate context
> ```

Is it possible to build an array from column-values in the next n rows?

Comment: It would be most helpful to provide the table definition and some sample values for your case, ideally in an SQLfiddle ([example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a44cc/1)) or something like that. And fix your statement while being at it, references to `a` are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine with Postgres 9.3:

```
SELECT week_value
     , array_agg(week_value) OVER(ORDER BY prod_name, week_date DESC
                                  ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 12 FOLLOWING)
FROM   tbl
```

[-> SQLfiddle for 9.3](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb4df/2)

But not in version 8.4:

[-> SQLfiddle for 8.4](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/cb4df/2)

The syntax `ROWS BETWEEN frame_start AND frame_end` was introduced with Postgres 9.0 and is not available in 8.4. Compare the [current manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) with its [8.4 counterpart](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

[Postgres 8.4 is rather old by now and reaching EOL this summer](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

If `array_agg` doesn't work in your version, then try this approach

```
WITH Q AS(
  SELECT week,
         row_number() over (order by week) rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT week,
       ( SELECT array_agg(q2.week) 
         FROM q q2
         WHERE q2.rn BETWEEN q1.rn
                     AND q1.rn + 12
       )
FROM q q1;
```

working demo (on 8.4.17) --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/7eda9/1

but it can be slow.